# no such table: TABLE_TEAM (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM TABLE_TEAM WHERE (TEAM_ID = '133604')

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have problem with database in android kotlin. everytime i trying to use it it always said there is no such table. but i has make the table.

this is my database open helper

```
    class MyDatabaseOpenHelper(ctx: Context) : ManagedSQLiteOpenHelper(ctx, "FavoriteTeam.db", null, 1) {
    companion object {
        private var instance: MyDatabaseOpenHelper? = null

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(ctx: Context): MyDatabaseOpenHelper {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = MyDatabaseOpenHelper(ctx.applicationContext)
            }
            return instance as MyDatabaseOpenHelper
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        // Here you create tables

        db?.createTable(FavoriteTeam.TABLE_TEAM, true,
                FavoriteTeam.ID to INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY + AUTOINCREMENT,
                FavoriteTeam.TEAM_ID to TEXT + UNIQUE,
                FavoriteTeam.TEAM_NAME to TEXT,
                FavoriteTeam.TEAM_BADGE to TEXT)

        db?.createTable(Favorite.TABLE_FAVORITE, true,
                Favorite.ID to INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY + AUTOINCREMENT,
                Favorite.EVENT_ID to TEXT + UNIQUE,
                Favorite.HOME_ID to TEXT + UNIQUE,
                Favorite.AWAY_ID to TEXT + UNIQUE,
                Favorite.TEAM_HOME to TEXT,
                Favorite.TEAM_AWAY to TEXT,
                Favorite.TEAM_HOME_SCORE to TEXT,
                Favorite.TEAM_AWAY_SCORE to TEXT,
                Favorite.DATE to TEXT)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        // Here you can upgrade tables, as usual
        db.dropTable(Favorite.TABLE_FAVORITE, true)
        db.dropTable(FavoriteTeam.TABLE_TEAM, true)
    }
}

// Access property for Context
val Context.database: MyDatabaseOpenHelper
    get() = MyDatabaseOpenHelper.getInstance(applicationContext)
```

this is my data for database

```
data class FavoriteTeam(val id: Long?, val teamId: String?, val teamName: String?, val teamBadge: String?) {

companion object {
    const val TABLE_TEAM: String = "TABLE_TEAM"
    const val ID: String = "ID_"
    const val TEAM_ID: String = "TEAM_ID"
    const val TEAM_NAME: String = "TEAM_NAME"
    const val TEAM_BADGE: String = "TEAM_BADGE"
}
```

}

and this is where i call it

```
private fun favoriteState() {
    database.use {
        val result = select(FavoriteTeam.TABLE_TEAM)
                .whereArgs("(TEAM_ID = {id})",
                        "id" to idTeam)
        val favorite = result.parseList(classParser<FavoriteTeam>())
        if (!favorite.isEmpty()) isFavorite = true
    }
}
```

and it always show this  error
`no such table: TABLE_TEAM (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM TABLE_TEAM WHERE (TEAM_ID = '133604')`

I don't know why. when i want to create table `TABLE_FAVORITE` it works well but when i want to create `TABLE_TEAM` it always shows what error whatever i want to insert or select. please help me if you know. thank you

Comment: first of all make sure that your table is created

Comment: just want to confirm ,you are overwriting application after changes in table?

Comment: You might have added the table after your database is created. Try after changing the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling the app and try again as TABLE creation is done in OnCreate which is called only once throughout the lifetime of the application so newly created TABLE won't reflect if it's old apk build or **re-create tables again in onUpgrade after dropping them**

Answer (score 0):

OnCreate basically wont create a table while running the project so, drop the table and run the project.